# Can I switch Circuit between Specific ExitNodes?

Tags: configuration, windows, help, ip-address

I want to use Specific ExitNodes and Switch between them only. I have tried modify TORRC using Code

> ExitNodes 153.126.210.34, 88.33.1.152, 103.28.53.138 , 104.200.20.46
>
> StrictNodes 1

But When I try to switch the ExitNodes Using CTRL+SHIFT+L it refreshes with the Same ExitNode. I want it to switch between the ExitNodes that i have Given.

Is there anyway to do What I'm Trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot make Tor Browser use one exit node, then the next, then the next ... etc. It will chose an exit from among the ones you listed, and sometimes it will use the same one two or more times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Like [pastly](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/20069/pastly) already said Tor Browser chooses it's relays on random.

However using [stem](https://stem.torproject.org) you **can** use a specific exit node. (https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html#custom-path-selection)